# Toggle two classes with AngularJS / jqLite on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class, angular-ng-class

I wan't to get a slideIn / slideOut animation by toggling the classes ***slideInRight*** and ***slideOutRight*** to a ul element.

I've tried it in different ways but I it only works with one className.

How can I add the class ***slideInRight*** on the first, and the class ***slideOutRight*** on the second click on my ul element with the class ***dropdown-menu***?

I've tried it this way:

```
angular.element('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(){
    angular.element('ul.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('slideOutRight slideInRight');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Hope you can help.

---

UPDATE:

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yIthpKYZwNvi60PzAHZj?p=preview) of the current state of my code. This way only the slideInRight animation works. If I click the button again, the ul disappears without the slideOutRight animation.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using angular's `ng-class`?

I'm sort of new to angular, but the way I did it was like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-class="ulOpen ? 'slideOutRight' : 'slideInRight'">
```

and the js

```
angular.element('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('.slideOutRight')) {
        ulOpen = true;
    } else {
        ulOpen = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions ntgCleaner. As with the approach of @jbrown, only the SlideInRight animation works. When I click the button again, the ul disappears without the slideOutRight animation

Comment: Here is a Plunker with the current state of my code: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yIthpKYZwNvi60PzAHZj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Add ulOpen to your controller as a scope variable

**Controller**

```
$scope.ulOpen = false;
```

**HTML**

Then you should rely on the angularjs directive ng-click to set the value of ulOpen:

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" ng-click="ulOpen=!ulOpen">Toggle Class</button>
```

And ng-class to switch class based on the value of ulOpen:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-class="slideOutRight: ulOpen, slideInRight: !ulOpen">
```

In general, I would recommend whenever possible you find the pure angularjs solution.  I find very few cases where there isn't a native angular directive that can handle what I would otherwise attempt to do in jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions jbrown. But this is way onle the SlideInRight anmation works. When I click the button again, the ul disappears without the slideOutRight animation.

Comment: Here is a Plunker with the current state of my code: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yIthpKYZwNvi60PzAHZj?p=preview)

Comment: @Codehan25 - the issue isn't with the usage of ng-class but instead there is something going on with bootstrap's dropdown-menu class and animate's slideOutRight/slideInRight classes.  You can see this by removing the dropdown-menu class from the ul element.  I'm no css expert but I'm guessing that the only way around this is to hack either or both of the bootstrap and animate css.  You may have to edit or repost your issue to draw attention from the css experts.